# Return corresponding row name instead of data in r

Tags: r, r-rownames

apologies in advance, I am a beginner trying to learn.
I have a dataframe which I have performed the max() function to return the maximum number of a particular column however I would like to return the corresponding row name of the max number as opposed to the max number itself.

Any help much appreciated

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the `row.names` vector with the index of the max value of the column.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100
)

row.names(df)[which(df$x == max(df$x, na.rm = TRUE))]

# "100"
```